# Definition of 'independence' of comparisons in Multiple-Comparison - Bonferroni Adjusted Standardized Residuals for Chi-Squared Test

Tags: chi-squared-test, multiple-comparisons, terminology, bonferroni

I have provided a hypothetical example to illustrate my question. Assume an alternate hypothesis for a difference between two variables of interest (arbitrary for the example), analyzed with a chi-squared contingency test (two-tailed).

Variable 1: 3 levels (categorical)

Variable 2: 2 levels (dichotomous)

I’ve kept this as a 3x2 to keep things simple, but my question would apply in larger comparisons (e.g. 4x2)

Assume you run an omnibus (chi-square) test which returns a significant result. You perform a multiple-comparison analysis, a standardized residuals approach with a Bonferroni correction for this example, to decompose where the significant effect was observed.

In this instance, everywhere I look online states that you would need to adjust the alpha level by 6 (i.e. 3x2 = 6 comparisons). I found a single instance of someone stating they thought it inappropriate to do this, as half of the comparisons will be mirror images of the others, i.e. they aren’t independent.

Visual for hypothetical example (random variable values and residuals were chosen)

```
|**Variable 1**|**Variable 2**|**Adjusted Residual**|**Significance**|
|--------------|--------------|---------------------|----------------|
|Level 1       |Yes           |-2.4                 |0.01639         |
|Level 1       |No            |2.4                  |0.01639         |
|Level 2       |Yes           |-0.7                 |0.48392         |
|Level 2       |No            |0.7                  |0.48392         |
|Level 3       |Yes           |-3.5                 |0.00046         |
|Level 3       |No            |3.5                  |0.00046         |
```

In each case, the residuals for each level of variable 1 are the same (differing only in the sign), e.g. Level 1 – Yes = -2.4, and Level 1 – No = 2.4. The corresponding p-value is also obviously the same in either case (as it is calculated from the absolute value of the standardized residual). As far as I can see, no useful information is being added by including these values. Adjusting the alpha level by 6 does seem redundant/erroneous, as half the comparisons are providing you with no new information. Is it therefore appropriate to conclude that there are only really 3 independent comparisons being made? And that you should adjust for 3, rather than 6?

I have read similar questions to this elsewhere, but none of them (or the responses) covered in any detail, why you would have to adjust for 6 comparisons even though half of them are basically identical. I am currently learning (novice) statistics & coding (Python) for data analysis in medical research, and can’t seem to find any resources on this issue.

Comment: Hi and welcome on the site! Can you be more specific about the articles/documents you've read and saying that you should perform a correction on all adjusted residuals of a contingency table with the configuration you describe? Not that the articles you've read are necessarily right, but it it's also possible that you might have misinterpreted some things.

Comment: In addition, you don't need p-values to "decompose where the significant effect was observed". You can simply look at the adjusted residuals and look at how they are structured in the table. The approach to take depends on the research question you want to answer ultimately.

Comment: I have been looking everywhere for someone to address this issue of the need for p-values for Chi Square post hoc testing. I am looking to publish results such as these and am currently reporting adjusted residuals. Do you have a paper I could refer to by any chance?